# Show the last text on scrollview

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a calculator app. I want the scroll view to scroll as I add new elements (numbers and signs) but it doesn't scroll. Once the text reaches the end of the screen I'm unable to see new elements until I manually scroll.

[image: Before it fills the screen]

Then

[image: after if fill the screen]

The remaining part of the text

[image: The remaining part of the text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)` after every text update.